# Different titles on homepage vs single based on category

Tags: customization, title

For better understanding what I need, I'll give as example the image below.
[image]

As you can see, on **CAT LOVERS** category, I have the full title as "Basic Health & Care Tips to Keep Your Cat Healthy".

Here I need to have a custom title like "Healthy Cat", on all pages (homepage, search results, tag, archive, author archives, etc) BUT keep the full title on single post page (Basic Health & Care Tips to Keep Your Cat Healthy).

There's an example:

[image]

I only need this for a specific category, Cat Lovers in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include your template code for the output?  What you'd need to do is conditionally check for the category, then change what gets output depending on whether or not the category is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the_title filter hook.

```
add_filter("the_title", function ($title) {

    if (!is_single() && !is_admin() && has_category("CAT LOVERS")) {
        return "Healthy Cat";
    }
    return $title;
});
```

Comment: I suppose that code will the same title (Healthy Cat) on ALL posts in Cat Lovers, right?
How about for multiple/custom titles?

Comment: Still need some help here :(